# C++ linkage error to JNI.h function impl_JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMArgs using java 8

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I try to implement a C++ DLL JNI Project. I get a linkage error to functions which are defined within `jni.h`.

```
Fehler  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes   
Symbol "__imp_JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs" in Funktion 
""public: virtual class TETraderAdapter * __cdecl 
TETraderAdapterFactoryJNI::createTraderAdapter(class 
std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > 
const &)"
```

I am sure that i configured all needed directories of the Java 8 64 bit installation.

The compilation works fine for Java 8 32 bit.
Is there any difference between 32bit and 64bit jvm concering JNI or are there any other issues which i have not concidered until now.

Comment: Well there certainly is. You need 64 bit compiled binaries to be used in a 64bit java jre environment. And vice versa for 32 bit.

Comment: yes i use the 64 bit JDK and try to compile with the 64bit configuration of Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you prove that your 64-bit build is linking to the 64bit jni library?

Comment: The directiories configured within the C++ Project point to the bin and lib folders of the 64 bit JDK. I can not proof if the Java distribution ships with a 64 bit jvm.lib but i suppose anything else would not make any sene to me. Botje

Comment: Are you also *linking* to the jvm libraries?